# Java Trying to Serialize Something That Doesn't Exist?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jcombobox

I made a class for saving the contents of a comboxbox and loading them. I use an `ObjectOutput` and save the model directly. Problem is, I get an exception:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.SpringLayout
```

I really don't understand why this is happening because I am not using a SpringLayout anywhere (that I can tell) in any of my code. I even set a breakpoint on the `stream.writeOutput(getModel());` and `getModel()` is definately returning a `DefaultComboboxModel`, so once again no mention of a Spring Layout.

Then I compile the code that I got the example from ([here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ComoboBoxloadsandsavesitemsautomaticallyfromafile.htm)) and it works fine. Why is this happening?

```
class MemComboBox extends JComboBox
{
    public static final int MAX_MEM_LEN = 30;

    public MemComboBox()
    {
        super();
        setEditable(true);
    }

    public void add(String item)
    {
        removeItem(item);
        insertItemAt(item, 0);
        setSelectedItem(item);
        if (getItemCount() > MAX_MEM_LEN)
            removeItemAt(getItemCount() - 1);
    }

    public void load(String fName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (getItemCount() > 0)
                removeAllItems();
            File f = new File(fName);
            if (!f.exists())
                return;
            FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(f);
            ObjectInput stream = new ObjectInputStream(fStream);

            Object obj = stream.readObject();
            if (obj instanceof ComboBoxModel)
                setModel((ComboBoxModel) obj);

            stream.close();
            fStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void save(String fName)
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fStream = new FileOutputStream(fName);
            ObjectOutput stream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);
            Object object = getModel();
            stream.writeObject(object);

            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            fStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I create the instance here:

```
    languageList = new MemComboBox();
    languageList.setBounds(146, 167, 166, 22);
    languageList.load(ClientInfo.GetAppData() + "/languages.xml");
    languageList.addActionListener(comboboxAdded);
    getContentPane().add(languageList);
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.SpringLayout
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.event.EventListenerList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.CCInc.Psyc.Windows.NewClient$MemComboBox.save(NewClient.java:688)
    at org.CCInc.Psyc.Windows.NewClient$7.windowClosing(NewClient.java:540)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.windowClosing(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JDialog.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is this the working code or the non-working code?

Comment: @EJP The code I posted is the non working code - the working code was in the [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ComoboBoxloadsandsavesitemsautomaticallyfromafile.htm)

Comment: And what is the difference between them?

Comment: ..none, I suppose. That's why I'm confused as to why it's not working :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more code I can't tell for sure, but...

The line `at org.CCInc.Psyc.Windows.NewClient$MemComboBox.save(NewClient.java:688)` in the stack trace indicates that the `MemComboBox` class is a inner class of your `NewClient` class. If it is not a static inner class then serialization will attempt to write out the entire 'NewClient' object. This is because there is a reference to the outer class in each non-static inner class.

Comment: Wow, that was it. I didn't know that that was a stipulation with serialization - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the stack trace. It is failing serializing a listener. At a guess the listener is an outer class, probably MyComboBox itself. Rework it so that the listener is a standalone class, and serializable, and without non-transient references to a Swing classes. Or else remove the listeners before serialization and restore them afterwards. Deserialized listeners can't do anything useful anyway, when you think about it.